# スタック・オーバーフローの画面説明がありますか

Tags: サポート

①スタック・オーバーフローの画面説明がありますか。外部リンクでもありますか。
②スタック・オーバーフローとstackoverflow（英語)の違いがわかれば、助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ①ツアーがありました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

一つ目の質問の画面説明とはどういう意味ですか？よくわかりません。

二つ目の質問のスタック・オーバーフローとStack Overflowの大きな違いは以下の通りです。

- URLに`ja`がある（英語だとない）
- 左上のロゴの下にスタック・オーバーフローと書いてある（英語だとない）
- サイトの言語が日本語である
- 英語の質問は[クローズ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)の対象である

  - 回答は削除対象???
- 日本語の方はまだBeta